# FOR v,e,p graph traversal AQL doesn't return all of the possible vertices

Tags: arangodb

My graph has a edge of kind pm_child that forms a tree structure.  Below is a picture showing an example tree:

[image: Visual Representation of graph]

When doing the following AQL command:

FOR v,e,p IN 1..50 OUTBOUND 'pmsite/482149696650' pm_child RETURN p

It returns only 14 of the 21 possible "project" kinds.  This seems like a bug but I wanted to verify I didn't do something silly before I report it.

Comment: can you share a sample dump reproducing the problem via gist? Only the structural information to reproduce the behaviour is needed.

Comment: If I did it right, the database should be here:
https://gist.github.com/ggendel/fb22d1b4b0b51e0ed93ebf26e1ad9a1f

I added three AQL traversal statements and the issues with each of them.

BTW, this is with ArangoDB 2.8.6

Comment: I think you'll need the document information as well or you won't be able to use the filters.  Let me know if you need that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a red-herring.  Arangojs introduced a default LIMIT value which truncated the results.  With some direction from ArangoDB support, I was able to construct a better way to pull out what I needed without the umpteen intermediate traversal results.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "arangojs introduced a default LIMIT value"? Neither the 4.x nor the 3.x versions of the driver should be adding limits to queries (though the ArangoDB HTTP API might on the server-side).

Comment: You could be right, I used the web interface to test the query and saw the missing items which matched the arangojs result.  I may have used an arangojs function that used this interface.